# GPS Device and Node implementation

Tags: node.js, gps

I want to track the live location of a truck.

Is it possible to interface a tracking device with nodejs? if yes, what kind of tracking device is compatible with node?

And links to helpful blog post or any resource that would guide me accomplish this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I love using Johnny-Five to interface nodejs with hardware. Here is a link to their examples using some common gps modules. http://johnny-five.io/api/gps/